# xcodebuild -exportArchive options plist values for thinning

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

The xcodebuild help says:

> thinning : String
>
> For non-App Store exports, should Xcode thin the package for one or
>   more device variants? Available options: <none> (Xcode produces a
>   non-thinned universal app), <thin-for-all-variants> (Xcode produces a
>   universal app and all available thinned variants), or a model
>   identifier for a specific device (e.g. "iPhone7,1"). Defaults to
>   <none>.

It's not clear if this is meant to be literal:

```
<key>thinning</key>
<string>&lt;none&gt;</string>
```

But then in my enterprise build I'm still seeing this phase occur:

```
2017-03-08 13:39:32.486 xcodebuild[43633:2535491] [MT] IDEDistribution: Step failed: <IDEDistributionThinningStep: 0x7fd756bef4e0>: Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=14 "No applicable devices found." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No applicable devices found.}
```

There isn't great documentation nor information online about this setting. Does anyone know definitively what values to use?

Comment: Hmm, maybe this is correct and maybe the thinning step occurs anyway? https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/132343#132343

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is absolutely literally `<string>&lt;none&gt;</string>`

In Xcode 7, here is a list of all options:

```
{<none>, <thin-for-all-variants>, iPad3,1, iPad3,2, iPad3,3, iPad3,4, iPad3,5, iPad3,6, iPad2,3, iPad2,1, iPad2,4, iPad2,2, iPad4,1, iPad4,2, iPad4,3, iPad5,3, iPad5,4, iPad6,7, iPad6,8, iPad6,3, iPad6,4, iPad2,5, iPad2,6, iPad2,7, iPad4,4, iPad4,5, iPad4,6, iPad4,7, iPad4,8, iPad4,9, iPad5,1, iPad5,2, iPhone4,1, iPhone5,1, iPhone5,2, iPhone5,3, iPhone5,4, iPhone6,1, iPhone6,2, iPhone7,2, iPhone7,1, iPhone8,1, iPhone8,2, iPhone8,4, iPod5,1, iPod7,1}
```